# apple not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK?

Tags: iphone, xcode

My binary was rejected with the error above as the reason.  I checked my xcode settings and under the "General" tab of info I have the Project Format set to Xcode 3.2 compatible which is the highest available.  I have the Base SDK Configurations set to iPhone Device 4.0 - also the highest available.  In the "Build" tab, I have the Base SDK set to iPhone Device 4.0.  I have all of them set to the highest, how can they not be receiving these types of apps?

EDIT:  I confirmed that I am using the newest version of Xcode (3.2.3) and I never had the beta test version installed - this is my first app.  I have confirmed that every single place that I can find - the OS is set to 4.0.  No matter what I seem to do - I still get that same error message when trying to upload the binary.

Comment: I have a same problem =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A certain combination needs to be made.  The Base SDK needs to be set to 4.0 and the target SDK needs to be set to 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Decompress your app (via show contents) and have a look at info.plist in a text editor such as textMate (its a binary file). Search for the key iphoneos the following numbers are the version.

This will confirm what version it was built with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the latest version of Xcode and the SDK to compile? Maybe you still have one of the beta versions installed and that's the reason for the rejection.

Comment: How can i tell if I still have a beta setup.  The xcode about menu says xcode 3.2.3 and the iphone SDK is set to 4.0.  It doesn't say anything about beta.